# Rebol localization

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I've been through some tutorials like [Cross Platform App Development with Rebol 3 Saphir](http://www.learnrebol.com/rebol3_book.html).

There it's mentioned the call to:

```
>> system/locale/months      
== [
    "January" "February" "March" "April" "May" "June"
    "July" "August" "September" "October" "November" "December"
]
```

and it returns the months in english.
Furthermore, in the gui `view` when I try to type an ISO-8859-15 character like `ç`, `á`, `à` the gui doesn't allow it.

I checked my LC settings:

```
$ set | grep LC_
LC_ALL=pt_PT
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MESSAGES=C
```

So, am I right to assume that an end user that doesn't speak English will have to adapt to the names of months in that language and will not be able to write in correct Portuguese (in this case, but it also applies to every other non-english language)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system/locale/months` can simply be updated to anything.

`system/locale/months: [ "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" ]`

GUI requesters should use the data from the `system` object (although I have not tested this). This can be conveniently added to your rebol.r file so it is loaded on start-up.

Note that the internal `date!` datatype will still expect English format months for input as the locale is used for display only.

Rebol 3 supports Unicode so it should be possible to use any characters in this block.

Comment: I tried again to write in a text box.  ç and Ç print correctly; a is shown instead of á;  `a instead of à; ^a instead of â. I'm using Version: 3.0.0.4.40   Platform:  Linux libc-x64

Comment: Can also the `money!` type be customized to place the euro sign `€` instead of the dollar one?  Can it be used as a suffix instead of a prefix?